# Insertar datos en un array bidimensional en con un for Java

Tags: java, array

Tengo que rellenar un array bidimensional de [20][20] con datos por teclado.
He mirado otros temas parecidos, pero no termino de entender ninguno, y me estoy desesperando porque no me sale una cosa que se que es simple, pero algo se me escapa.

Tengo esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader flujo = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader teclado = new BufferedReader(flujo);

        String auxS = "";
        String elementos[][] = new String[2][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < elementos[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Estado");
                auxS = teclado.readLine();
                elementos[i][j] = auxS;
                System.out.println("Elemento");
                auxS = teclado.readLine();
                elementos[i][j] = auxS;

            }
        }
        for( int x = 0; x<elementos.length;x++) {
            for( int z = 0; z<elementos.length;z++) {
                System.out.println("Estado "+elementos[x][z]);
                System.out.println("Elemento "+elementos[z][z]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que necesito es tener [elemento][estado] [Agua][Liquido] asi 20x20. Esto me devuelve elemento->Agua estado->Agua.
Mas que una solucion, quiero saber como voy elm est, elm est en el bucle.Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que veo es que en el primer bucle, en la misma dirección del array estás poniendo los dos valores. Estás preguntando por dos datos, pero no mueves el puntero. Una solución podría ser:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < elementos[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println(j == 0 ? "Estado" : "Elemento");
        auxS = teclado.readLine();
        elementos[i][j] = auxS;
    }
}
```

Otra forma posible de hacerlo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Estado: ");
    auxS = teclado.readLine();
    elementos[i][0] = auxS;
    System.out.println("Elemento: ");
    auxS = teclado.readLine();
    elementos[i][1] = auxS;
}
```

Por otro lado, cuando presentas los datos por pantalla podrías poner esto:

```
for (int x = 0; x < elementos.length; x++) {
        System.out.println("Estado " + elementos[x][0]);
        System.out.println("Elemento " + elementos[x][1]);
}
```

O de esta otra forma:

```
for (int x = 0; x < elementos.length; x++) {
    for (int z = 0; z < elementos.length; z++) {
        System.out.println((z == 0 ? "Estado " : "Elemento ") + elementos[x][z]);
    }
}
```

Para poder hacer algo parecido a un array asociativo al estilo, por ejemplo, de PHP, con parejas de clave/valor necesitarías utilizar las colecciones de tipo Map, HashMap, HashTable, TreeMap etc...

También puedes crear algo parecido tú mismo, pero eso ya depende de ti.